# Preferred Method for Binding .keydown to Different AngularJS Views

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Title pretty much says it all. Does anyone know the preferred method for binding .keydown to different AngularJS views?

Which way can help me improve the performance of my apps in the long run? And which way is the standard?

Comment: I'm not sure the title does say it all. You don't really bind a keydown event to a view, you bind it to a specific element. Can you give a use case?

Comment: $(document).keydown doing different things on different views

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive and attach it to your body element. Technically you could attach it anywhere with code like this but if you want it to register a keydown even ANYWHERE on your body then for readability purposes it's best to do it there.

```
angular.directive("pressKeyDown", function(){
    return {
       restrict: "A",
       link: function(scope, element, attrs){
              var doc = angular.element(document.body);
              doc.on("keydown", function(e){
                   console.log("This is the event", e);
              }
       }
   }
});
```

The HTML.

```
<body press-key-down>
    //html here
</body>
```